Contourn integration with gaussian-like argument
I'm currently working on evaluating the following integral:
$$
I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{a-x^2+b}{(a-x^2)^2}e^{-i c x^2}dx,
$$
where $a,b,c$ are real and positive constants.
I wish to compute this integral by contourn integration.
I intend to compute this integral using contour integration.
Now, in order to proceed, I'm uncertain about how to handle the $x^2$ term in the exponential (specifically, I'm unsure about closing the contour). Therefore, I attempted to modify the integrand. Initially, I noticed that:
$$
I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{a-x^2+b}{(a-x^2)^2}e^{-i c x^2}dx=2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{a-x^2+b}{(a-x^2)^2}e^{-i c x^2},
$$
so that after defining $t=x^2$, the integral becomes
$$
I=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{a-t+b}{(a-t)^2\sqrt{t}}e^{-i c t}dt
$$
In this scenario, there is a pole at $t=a$, and a contour closed below the real axis implies that:
$$
e^{-i c t}\Bigg|_{t\to-i\infty}\to0,
$$
However, I am now uncertain about how to handle the branch of $\sqrt{t}$, because the exponential factor, I think I cannot close a contourn from above and make $R\to\infty$ as this:

I would appreciate any help or further comments on how to proceed with this integral.
Edited
I think that the original integral
$$
I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{a-x^2+b}{(a-x^2)^2}e^{-i c x^2}dx,
$$
can be evaluated in the following contourn:

so that
$$
I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{a-x^2+b}{(a-x^2)^2}e^{-i c x^2}dx=2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{a-x^2+b}{(a-x^2)^2}e^{-i c x^2}dx\to \oint_C\frac{a-z^2+b}{(a-z^2)^2}e^{-i c z^2}dz=0
$$
Or maybe it is convenient to include the pole inside the contounr in order to apply the Cauchy's theorem.

It looks like your first integral diverges- you have a non-integrable singularity right on the contour due to the $1/(a-x^2)^2$ bit
